# How can an Android photosphere be used as a scene background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scene

How can an Android photosphere be used as a scene background?

Should I map it onto a sphere? Is there a feature of background images I can use from scene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a easy way;

## Cycles

Just go to the Node Editor, change the type to *World*.

[image]

Then, check `Use Nodes`, if it isn't already, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and add a Texture>Environment Texture node; Point the to your file, and connect it to the Background node.

If you don't like/understand the Node Editor, you can go to the Properties, switch to the World tab, and click `Use Nodes`, then besides the `Color` field, click the dot, and select Texture>Environment Texture and point it to your image.

---

## Blender Internal

Go to the Properties panel, switch to the World tab, go to the World subsection, and check `Blend Sky` and `Real Sky`.

[image]
Then go to the Texture tab, click `New` click `World` under Preview and open your image. Scroll down to the `Influence` subsection and check 'Zenith Up', `Zenith Down`, `Horizon` and `Blend`.

Then go to the `Mapping`, and change the `Coordinate` field from View to Equirectangular.